# MongoDB shell to show actions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I get my Mongo shell to show live operations?  Do I need to authorize a user?  I am trying to use `db.currentOp(true)` but I am getting authorization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. if you are using *--auth* option in your database configuration, then you needs to be authorized first. after that it should work.